# Is it possible to query multiple separate entities in one CRM call?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, dynamics-crm

I am working in a project that requires performing matching user input data from xlsx files with the Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

I have a method that performs the matching.

```
public EntityViewModel Match(EntityViewModel inputEntity)
{

    try
    {

        // Connect to the Organization service.
        // The using statement assures that the service proxy will be properly disposed.
        using (var serviceProxy = CrmServiceFactory.CreateNew())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputEntity.ClientName))
                CrmHelper.ClientMatch(serviceProxy, inputEntity);

            var product = false;

            if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputEntity.Category) || inputEntity.Category != revenuecategoryos.Insurance.ToString())
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputEntity.ProductName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputEntity.ProductNumber) && inputEntity.ClientId != Guid.Empty)
            {

                product = CrmHelper.ClientAssetMatch(serviceProxy, inputEntity);
            }


            if (((string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputEntity.Category) && !product) || inputEntity.Category == revenuecategoryos.Insurance.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputEntity.ProductNumber) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputEntity.ProductName))
            {

                CrmHelper.InsuranceMatch(serviceProxy, inputEntity);                
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputEntity.ProductProvider) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputEntity.ProductNumber) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputEntity.ProductName))
            {

                CrmHelper.ProviderMatch(serviceProxy, inputEntity);
            }

            if (inputEntity.Type == revenuetypeos.Upfront.ToString() && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputEntity.Opportunity))
            {

                CrmHelper.OpportunityMatch(serviceProxy, inputEntity);
            }

            return inputEntity;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle the exception
    }
}
```

As you can see, it calls 5 methods to perform matching. They query 5 different, separate entities.

```
internal static bool ClientMatch(IOrganizationService crm, EntityViewModel inputEntity)
{
    #region Using Retrieve Multiple

    // Create a column set holding the names of the columns to be retrieved.
    var cols = new ColumnSet("fullname");

    // Create the query.
    var query = new QueryExpression
    {
        EntityName = Xrm.Contact.EntityLogicalName,
        ColumnSet = cols
    };

    query.Criteria.AddCondition("fullname", ConditionOperator.Equal, inputEntity.ClientName);
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)ContactState.Active);

    // Create the request object.
    var clientList = crm.RetrieveMultiple(query);

    // If there's not only one existing record in CRM with this key value
    if (recordList == null || recordList.Entities == null || recordList.Entities.Count != 1)
    {
        // if we couldn't find only one record with same key value (maybe none, maybe multiple records)
        query.Criteria.Conditions.Clear();

        query.Criteria.AddCondition("importmetadata", ConditionOperator.Like,
            string.Format("%{0}, {1}, {2}%", inputEntity.ProductName, inputEntity.ProductNumber, inputEntity.ProductProvider));
        query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)ContactState.Active);

        recordList = crm.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    }

    if (recordList != null && recordList.Entities != null && recordList.Entities.Count == 1)
    {
        var client = recordList.Entities[0];

        inputEntity.ClientId = client.Id;
        inputEntity.ClientName = client.Attributes.Contains("fullname") ? client.Attributes["fullname"].ToString() : string.Empty;

        return true;
    }

    return false;

    #endregion Using Retrieve Multiple
}

internal static bool ClientAssetMatch(IOrganizationService crm, EntityViewModel inputEntity)
{
    #region Using Retrieve Multiple

    // Create a column set holding the names of the columns to be retrieved.
    var cols = new ColumnSet(new[] { "assetname", "accountnumber", "revenuecategory" });

    // Build the filter based on the condition.
    var filter = new FilterExpression
    {
        FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And
    };
    filter.AddCondition("contactid", ConditionOperator.Equal, inputEntity.ClientId);

    // Create a LinkEntity to link the owner's information to the account.
    var link = new LinkEntity
    {
        LinkCriteria = filter,
        LinkFromEntityName = clientasset.EntityLogicalName,
        LinkFromAttributeName = "primaryclient",
        LinkToEntityName = Xrm.Contact.EntityLogicalName,
        LinkToAttributeName = "contactid"
    };

    // Create the query.
    var query = new QueryExpression
    {
        EntityName = clientasset.EntityLogicalName,
        ColumnSet = cols
    };

    query.LinkEntities.Add(link);

    query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)clientassetState.Active);
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("assetname", ConditionOperator.Equal, inputEntity.ProductName);
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("accountnumber", ConditionOperator.Equal, inputEntity.ProductNumber);

    // Create the request object.
    var recordList = crm.RetrieveMultiple(query);

    if (recordList == null || recordList.Entities == null || recordList.Entities.Count != 1)
    {
        // if we couldn't find only one record with same key value (maybe none, maybe multiple records)
        query.Criteria.Conditions.Clear();

        query.Criteria.AddCondition("importmetadata", ConditionOperator.Like,
            string.Format("%{0}, {1}%", inputEntity.ProductName, inputEntity.ProductNumber));
        query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)clientassetState.Active);

        recordList = crm.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    }

    if (recordList.Entities.Count == 1)
    {
        var client = recordList.Entities[0];

        inputEntity.ProductId = client.Id;
        inputEntity.ProductName = client.Attributes.Contains("assetname") ? client.Attributes["assetname"].ToString() : string.Empty;
        inputEntity.ProductNumber = client.Attributes.Contains("accountnumber") ? client.Attributes["accountnumber"].ToString() : string.Empty;
        inputEntity.IsClientAsset = true;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputEntity.Category) && client.Attributes.Contains("revenuecategory") && client.Attributes["revenuecategory"] != null)
            inputEntity.Category = GetCategory(((OptionSetValue)client.Attributes["revenuecategory"]).Value);

        return true;
    }

    return false;

    #endregion Using Retrieve Multiple
}

internal static bool InsuranceMatch(IOrganizationService crm, EntityViewModel inputEntity)
{
    #region Using Retrieve Multiple

    // Create a column set holding the names of the columns to be retrieved.
    var cols = new ColumnSet(new[] { "name", "policynumber" });

    // Build the filter based on the condition.
    var filter = new FilterExpression
    {
        FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And
    };
    filter.AddCondition("contactid", ConditionOperator.Equal, inputEntity.ClientId);

    // Create a LinkEntity to link the owner's information to the account.
    var link = new LinkEntity
    {
        LinkCriteria = filter,
        LinkFromEntityName = personalinsurance.EntityLogicalName,
        LinkFromAttributeName = "individualowner",
        LinkToEntityName = Xrm.Contact.EntityLogicalName,
        LinkToAttributeName = "contactid"
    };

    // Create the query.
    var query = new QueryExpression
    {
        EntityName = personalinsurance.EntityLogicalName,
        ColumnSet = cols
    };

    query.LinkEntities.Add(link);


    query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)personalinsuranceState.Active);
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, inputEntity.ProductName);
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("policynumber", ConditionOperator.Equal, inputEntity.ProductNumber);

    // Create the request object.
    var recordList = crm.RetrieveMultiple(query);

    if (recordList == null || recordList.Entities == null || recordList.Entities.Count != 1)
    {
        // if we couldn't find only one record with same key value (maybe none, maybe multiple records)
        query.Criteria.Conditions.Clear();
        query.Criteria.AddCondition("importmetadata", ConditionOperator.Like,
            string.Format("%{0}, {1}%", inputEntity.ProductName, inputEntity.ProductNumber));
        query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)personalinsuranceState.Active);

        recordList = crm.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    }

    if (recordList.Entities.Count == 1)
    {
        var client = recordList.Entities[0];

        inputEntity.ProductId = client.Id;
        inputEntity.ProductName = client.Attributes.Contains("name") ? client.Attributes["name"].ToString() : string.Empty;
        inputEntity.ProductNumber = client.Attributes.Contains("policynumber") ? client.Attributes["policynumber"].ToString() : string.Empty;
        inputEntity.IsClientAsset = false;

        // If it's a personal insurance, it's always an Insurance Revenue Category type
        inputEntity.Category = revenuecategoryos.Insurance.ToString();

        return true;
    }

    return false;

    #endregion Using Retrieve Multiple
}
internal static bool ProviderMatch(IOrganizationService crm, EntityViewModel inputEntity)
{
    #region Using Retrieve Multiple

    // Create a column set holding the names of the columns to be retrieved.
    var cols = new ColumnSet("name");

    // Create the query.
    var query = new QueryExpression
    {
        EntityName = Account.EntityLogicalName,
        ColumnSet = cols
    };

    query.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, inputEntity.ProductProvider);
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)AccountState.Active);

    // Create the request object.
    var recordList = crm.RetrieveMultiple(query);

    // If there's not only one existing record in CRM with this key value

    if (recordList == null || recordList.Entities == null || recordList.Entities.Count != 1)
    {
        // if we couldn't find only one record with same key value (maybe none, maybe multiple records)
        query.Criteria.Conditions.Clear();

        query.Criteria.AddCondition("importmetadata", ConditionOperator.Like, "%" + inputEntity.ProductProvider + "%");
        query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)AccountState.Active);

        recordList = crm.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    }

    if (recordList != null && recordList.Entities != null && recordList.Entities.Count == 1)
    {
        var client = recordList.Entities[0];

        inputEntity.ProductProviderId = client.Id;
        inputEntity.ProductProvider = client.Attributes.Contains("name") ? client.Attributes["name"].ToString() : string.Empty;

        return true;
    }

    return false;

    #endregion Using Retrieve Multiple
}
internal static bool OpportunityMatch(IOrganizationService crm, EntityViewModel inputEntity)
{
    #region Using Retrieve Multiple

    // Create a column set holding the names of the columns to be retrieved.
    var cols = new ColumnSet("name");

    // Create the query.
    var query = new QueryExpression
    {
        EntityName = Opportunity.EntityLogicalName,
        ColumnSet = cols
    };

    query.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, inputEntity.Opportunity);
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, (int)OpportunityState.Lost);

    // Create the request object.
    var opportunityList = crm.RetrieveMultiple(query);

    // If there's not only one existing record in CRM with this key value
    if (opportunityList == null || opportunityList.Entities == null || opportunityList.Entities.Count != 1)
    {
        // if we couldn't find only one record with same key value (maybe none, maybe multiple records)
        query.Criteria.Conditions.Clear();

        query.Criteria.AddCondition("importmetadata", ConditionOperator.Like, "%" + inputEntity.Opportunity + "%");
        query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, (int)OpportunityState.Lost);

        opportunityList = crm.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    }

    if (recordList != null && recordList.Entities != null && recordList.Entities.Count == 1)
    {
        var opportunity = recordList.Entities[0];

        inputEntity.OpportunityId = opportunity.Id;
        inputEntity.Opportunity = opportunity.Attributes.Contains("name") ? opportunity.Attributes["name"].ToString() : string.Empty;

        return true;
    }

    return false;

    #endregion Using Retrieve Multiple
}
```

Normally this code works fine with small excel files with less than 15 rows. But when user inputs bigger files, the performance is extremely slow, especially if there are 2 or more users upload their files at the same time (because the entire matching process is managed by a queue triggered webjob). I tried to implement multitasking for matching multiple items at the same time but nothing changed.

I have been thinking that perhaps what I need is to find some way to merge 5 functions above together. But so far, I can't seem to find any way to do that. 
The method RetrieveMultiple of interface IOrganizationService seems can process only one QueryExpression object at a time. The 5 entities listed above are separate. My question is is it possible to query them in one crm call? If so, how? And if not, is there any other way to improve the performance? Our customers certainly don't want to spend more than 10 minutes to wait for the matching process. They need something faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can try using the [ExecuteMultipleRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.executemultiplerequest.aspx) class to see if that gives you any performance improvement.

Here's an example of sending four RetrieveMultipleRequests for accounts and four for contacts in one multi-request, and printing the names of the results. You'll need to adapt it to handle the queries for the entities you need, but querying five separate entities should work fine.

Output:

[image: Ouput]

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class App_ExecuteMultiple 
    {
        private IOrganizationService svc;

        public App_ExecuteMultiple(IOrganizationService svc) 
        {
            this.svc = svc;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            var multiReq = new ExecuteMultipleRequest()
            {
                Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
                {
                    ContinueOnError = true,
                    ReturnResponses = true
                },            
                Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
            };

            accountIds().ForEach(i => multiReq.Requests.Add(getAccountRequest(i)));

            contactIds().ForEach(i => multiReq.Requests.Add(getContactRequest(i)));

            var multiResponse = (ExecuteMultipleResponse)svc.Execute(multiReq);

            foreach (var singleResponse in multiResponse.Responses)
            {
                var retrieveResponse = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)singleResponse.Response;

                var attributeName = "";

                var logicalName = retrieveResponse.EntityCollection[0].LogicalName;

                if ( logicalName == "account")
                {
                    attributeName = "name";
                }
                else if (logicalName == "contact")
                {
                    attributeName = "fullname";
                }

                var name = retrieveResponse.EntityCollection[0].GetAttributeValue<string>(attributeName);

                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }
        }

        private RetrieveMultipleRequest getAccountRequest(Guid id)
        {
            return new RetrieveMultipleRequest
            {
                Query = getAccountQuery(id)
            };
        }

        private QueryExpression getAccountQuery(Guid id)
        {
            return new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = "account",
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
                Criteria = new FilterExpression
                {
                    FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                    Conditions =
                    {
                        new ConditionExpression
                        {
                            AttributeName = "accountid",
                            Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                            Values = { id }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        private List<Guid> accountIds()
        {
            return new List<Guid>
            {
                new Guid("{04C82C07-98F1-E611-9438-00155D6FD706}"),
                new Guid("{06C82C07-98F1-E611-9438-00155D6FD706}"),
                new Guid("{08C82C07-98F1-E611-9438-00155D6FD706}"),
                new Guid("{0AC82C07-98F1-E611-9438-00155D6FD706}")
            };
        }

        private RetrieveMultipleRequest getContactRequest(Guid id)
        {
            return new RetrieveMultipleRequest
            {
                Query = getContactQuery(id)
            };
        }

        private QueryExpression getContactQuery(Guid id)
        {
            return new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = "contact",
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
                Criteria = new FilterExpression
                {
                    FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                    Conditions =
                    {
                        new ConditionExpression
                        {
                            AttributeName = "contactid",
                            Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                            Values = { id }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        private List<Guid> contactIds()
        {
            return new List<Guid>
            {
                new Guid("{6AC82C07-98F1-E611-9438-00155D6FD706}"),
                new Guid("{6CC82C07-98F1-E611-9438-00155D6FD706}"),
                new Guid("{6EC82C07-98F1-E611-9438-00155D6FD706}"),
                new Guid("{70C82C07-98F1-E611-9438-00155D6FD706}")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know if it can solve the problem.

Comment: ok I'm integrating it in. Seems ok, but one thing that is still bugging me is that what if 1 query relies on the output result of another one? 

As you can see in my code above, method "CrmHelper.MatchPersonalInsurance(serviceProxy, revenueEntity);" will run only if value of "product" returns by method "CrmHelper.MatchClientAsset(serviceProxy, revenueEntity);" is false.

How can I make sure that this RetrieveMultipleRequest object shall rely on the result of another RetrieveMultipleRequest object?

Comment: Any that have dependents you'll have to run first - either individually or in their own batch. Even though there are 5 queries, 10 minutes seems like a very long time for it to take. Are there large numbers of records in one or more of the entities you're querying? Also, you may want to look into the out-of-box alternate key functionality.

Comment: Their business is expanding. Previously maximum 15 or 20 rows per file. Now 200, 300 and sometimes even 400.

Comment: Instead of doing "double" queries by checking one set of conditions then changing the conditions and querying again, maybe query once per entity with all the possible conditions, then filter locally via LINQ.

Comment: Hi @Aron, I applied your ideas and everything looks good. The performance was slightly improved. Now I'm trying to match multiple entities (a list of MatchRevenueEntityViewModel objects) in one call to improve the performance. Each object's matching process must go through all 5 steps. What I want to know now is how to get the requested entity back from response? Do you know how to get MatchRevenueEntityViewModel object from singleResponse or retrieveResponse? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at creating [alternate keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932139.aspx) on each of the entities your searching in. Also, when you say, "how to get the requested entity back from response", please post the code so we can see what response we're talking about.

Comment: Hi @Aron, I posted the source code below. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: To use MatchRevenueEntityViewModel objects in C# you have to generate a proxy class for the entity with [CrmSvcUtil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx). The XrmToolbox contains [Daryl LaBar's Early Bound Generator](https://github.com/daryllabar/DLaB.Xrm.XrmToolBoxTools) to assist with the process. I use a commercial Visual Studio add-on called [XrmToolkit](https://www.xrmtoolkit.com) to generate proxy classes. Once you have the proxy class you can do `var x=myEntity.ToEntity<MatchRevenueEntityViewModel>()` or  `var x=new MatchRevenueEntityViewModel(myEntity)`